# when locust is running in master mode , how to set global variable

Tags: locust

when locust is running in master and worker mode, how to set a global variable?
for example, I need unique id for each loccust vuser

```
from locust import HttpUser, constant, task, TaskSet
from queue import Queue

class Tasks(TaskSet):

    @task
    def add_task(self):
        tid = self.user.q.get_nowait()
        data = {'taskId': tid}
        self.client.post("/xx", json=data)


class User(HttpUser):
    tasks = [Tasks]
    wait_time = constant(1)
    q = Queue()
    for i in range(40):
        q.put(str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a [Singleton](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_singleton.htm) class where you will store all that you need and initialize this singleton class in your `User(HttpUser)`